# Подключение HTTP_Request2

Tags: php, apache

При подключении `require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';` генерирует ошибку 500 (Страница не работает). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы уверены, что путь верный? По теме: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220882/error-500-require-once
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868718/require-once-function-causing-a-server-error

Comment: Нет. В папке с доменом нет таких папок и файлов

Comment: А должна быть, раз подключаете.

Comment: а разве это не какой то модуль который нужно устанавливать через командную строку?

Comment: любом непонятном случае используй:
    `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

А потом гугли ошибку :)
ЗЫ: Добавь эти строки сразу после `<?php` и обнови страницу.

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: open_basedir restriction in effect. File ... is not within the allowed path(s):
(/path/to/dir1:/path/to/dir2) in /path/to/dir/filename.php on line 14
```

Это сообщение указывает на то, что путь к директории установки WebAsyst не включен в список допустимых путей, указанных в параметре open_basedir в конфигурации PHP. Параметр open_basedir содержит список директорий, содержимое которых разрешено считывать средствами PHP-скриптов.

Один из способов решения этой проблемы – добавить путь к директории установки WebAsyst в значение параметра open_basedir.
На сервере с операционной системой UNIX/Linux/FreeBSD пути к разрешенным директориям должны быть разделены двоеточием, например:

```
open_basedir =/home/vhosts:/usr/share/php/pear/:/tmp
```

На Windows-сервере пути должны быть разделены точкой с запятой, например:

```
open_basedir = C:\Inetpub;C:\Windows\TEMP
```

Другой способ – отменить ограничения `open_basedir` и открыть доступ ко всем директориям, указав значение none:

```
open_basedir = none
```

Comment: Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/pear/Net/URL2.php) is not within the allowed path(s):

Comment: Так погугли)
http://old.webasyst.ru/support/help/open-basedir.html

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/149486)

Comment: @Vadizar вообще, человек написал "в чем может быть проблема?". Я показал, как посмотреть в чем может быть проблема. Разве не так?

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev это вы сейчас исправили ответ, до этого это было непонятно что. "Гугли ошибку" - это не ответ.

Comment: open_basedir = none не помогло. Та же ошибка

Comment: @Vadizar а я не говорю за новый ответ, я говорю за старый, в котором было указано, как посмотреть ошибку. Разве он был неверен?

Comment: @antonin14d службу httpd перезапустил?

Comment: перезапустил сервер

Comment: Посмотри phpinfo(); изменился ли параметр?